# Using gdistance transition function in R to limit the directions of travel/calculation

Tags: raster, r, distance-matrix, direction, cost-surface

I want to use gdistance to calculate a an accumulate cost distance. My input consists of a cost surface raster and a point shapefile. This would usually be straightforward but I want to limit the directions in which cost is calculated (NW, N, and NE). In other words, with each step, it can only sum going in those directions from each cell. Is this feasible?